# Creating separate list of a custom content type for every user

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I have a custom content type named Movie.

Every user must have 2 lists of movies :-

1) Seen Movies

2) Unseen Movies

For this purpose a ADD button (or 2 buttons - 1. add to seen, and 2. add to unseen) should appear on every movie page , by which a user can add the corresponding movie to his seen list or unseen list.

How can i do this??

I am using Drupal 7.

I am new to drupal, so what should be my approach to solve this problem ?? Please help :-)

THANX IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look a the [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module. It allows you to create an unlimited number of "flags" that can be placed on nodes that users can select/deselect. You could create one for "seen" and "unseen".

It has views support so you can create a view using the user id as an argument on each user's page that will show them which movies that have flagged.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works :-)

How can I make the 2 flags mutually exclusive ?? That is if an user flags one movie with "seen" , he cant flag it with "unseen"

Thanks again

Comment: Flag has rules integration so you could use that to unflag "unseen" if someone presses "seen". It won't update automatically on the screen if they are both on the same node. Not sure if there is a way to do that through flag but you could use some custom jquery to do so using: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ . You might want to create a separate question for your follow up if that doesn't work.

Comment: I successfully made the two list "Seen" and "Unseen" using Views for individual users .A user can see it when he logs in. But what i need is, one user can see other user's lists , how can I achieve that ??

That is i want to maintain a profile for each user , what other users can visit . Each profile should contain those lists.